# What is wrong with my query in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql

I am trying to fill a gridview by taking data from multiple tables. Here is my code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = Userfunctions.GetConnectionString();
        con.Open();

            string query = "SELECT RegisterTable.CourseCode,
RegisterTable.courseNumber,
RegisterTable.Term,RegisterTable.Grade,
CourseTable.CourseName,
CourseTable.Level,
CourseTable.Credit 
FROM RegisterTable,CourseTable 
WHERE StudentID='" + MyGlobals.currentID + "' and 
RegisterTable.CourseCode=CourseTable.CourseCode and 
RegisterTable.CourseNumber=CourseTable.CourseNumber and 
RegisterTable.Term=CourseTable.Term";




        SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);

        DataTable tab = new DataTable();

        adap.Fill(tab);

        GridView1.DataSource = tab;
        GridView1.DataBind();


}
```

This gives an error saying that "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'." Can anyone help me with this?  Thanks

### EDIT:

### Ignore the string's lack of concatenation. It was all on one line and you had to scroll for a mile to see it all. They just made it easier to see.

Comment: Have you ran your query in your SQL environment (which you should have tagged in your question) and it worked? If so, then it's probably MyGlobals.currentID being null or something.

Comment: Also, you should be using parameterized SQL or stored procedures for this in general. If MyGlobals.currentID is being set through user entry, you could be wide open for SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Aside from the fact that you're embedding queries in your page as literal strings, building the query to be executed using string concatenation, not closing your SQL connection, and have classes called "MyGlobals" and "Userfunctions"? Is this homework?

Comment: Well, beeeeeeesiiiides that, @DavidLively, why is WHERE not working. =)

Comment: @Yatrix - thank you for putting in the edit above :)

Comment: @chuex you're welcome. People tend to see a few up-votes and think the problem is solved. Important thing is, we help Mr. HardcodedQuery out. =)

Comment: @Yatrix - I know, that's why I deleted my answer

Comment: @chuex That's honorable of you. I up-voted two of your correctly accepted answers so you get that +20. Good job.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried re-writing your query (so it's not using a cross-join)?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = null;
    SqlCommand cmd = null;
    SqlDataAdapter adap = null;
    string query = string.Empty();
    DataSet ds = null;
    DataTable tab = null;

    con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = Userfunctions.GetConnectionString();
    query = "SELECT RegisterTable.CourseCode, RegisterTable.CourseNumber, RegisterTable.Term, RegisterTable.Grade, CourseTable.CourseName, CourseTable.Level, CourseTable.Credit FROM RegisterTable INNER JOIN CourseTable ON RegisterTable.CourseCode = CourseTable.CourseCode AND RegisterTable.CourseNumber = CourseTable.CourseNumber AND RegisterTable.Term = CourseTable.Term WHERE StudentID = @StudentID;";

    cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("StudentID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = MyGlobals.currentID;

    ds = new DataSet();
    adap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    adap.Fill(ds);

    if (ds.Tables.Count > 0) {
        tab = ds.Tables(0);
    }

    GridView1.DataSource = tab;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```